# Is there away to put a colored background in a wpf popup?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, background, popup

Is there a way to put a background color in a WPF popup in XAML.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A WPF `Popup` has no default visual appearance. It is merely a place holder for content that needs to *popup*.

Simply have your `Popup` contain an item that does have a `Background` property and set that to your desired color as in this example from the [Popup class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.aspx) documentation.

```
<Popup Name="myPopup">
    <TextBlock Name="myPopupText" 
               Background="LightBlue" 
               Foreground="Blue">
        Popup Text
  </TextBlock>
</Popup>
```

Comment: Thanks! I was just trying to put the background in the wrong place... Long day lol.

Comment: I had to set Popup `UseLayoutRounding="True"` to avoid a black 1px gap on the right side.